# How is serial up-voting handled on small beta sites?

Tags: discussion, questions

A new member joined the Contract Bridge community on https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/ today, and spent time reviewing recent Q & A on Bridge. As I have recently answered many of these questions, this new member has expressed appreciation for several of my answers by up-voting them. Are these up-votes likely to be rolled-back?

The Contract Bridge sub-community on Board Games is likely less than a dozen active members, and fewer still who are competent enough to answer sensibly. It seems inappropriate to roll-back up-votes made by a competent and knowledgeable new member in this circumstance.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if someone's actually *reading* the stuff they're voting on, and isn't just fixated on one person's profile... They have nothing to worry about. If (as someone tried to claim once) they build a list throughout the day of stuff they've found to vote on, then at the end sort it by author and vote on it all as quickly as humanly possible... Then they're probably gonna be in trouble. But then, that's insane.

Comment: @Shog9: Thank you for the daily smile, and for the observations from a moderator perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of the upvotes occurred within the span of a few minutes, the answer is very likely to be yes.

If this is the upvote sequence you're referring to:

[image: image of reputation]

Then I would say the answer is likely to be no. Spread over three hours, it's reasonable for the system to assume that the user didn't go through your answers upvoting.

Still, it remains to be seen. We can no longer see how close together those three upvotes an hour ago were, which will very heavily impact the script. The behavior of the script is generally unknown, as well, so it may be the case that *just* those three upvotes are reverted.

Edit: Apparently mouseovers reveal exact timestamps! Thanks Anna! Those upvotes occurred a significant time apart. I would be surprised if they triggered the reversal script.

So, in short, the only answer we can give you is: You're going to have to wait and see. You'll know tomorrow.

Comment: Hint: mouseover for exact timestamps.

Comment: Yes, that is the sequence I just observed.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I've edited my answer - based on the exact timestamps (Thanks, Anna!), I would be surprised if they triggered the reversal script.

Answer (score 4):

Moderators take the size of the community into account when manually investigating potential vote fraud. If the reason that a user upvoted many posts by another users is just that they are active in the same small tag, this is something a moderator will usually notice.

The automatic serial voting script is the same everywhere, and this will reverse anomalous vote patterns. But you should only hit that when going through another users account and voting on their posts in quick succession, it is unlikely that you hit it naturally.